# Prevent printcp from printing?

Tags: r

I have some code where I fit a tree and then automatically prune the tree back by selecting the complexity parameter such that it minimizes the cross validation error, as displayed by the `printcp()` function. In digesting my console output, I am annoyed by the mass that is printed out by `printcp()`.

What I do is I convert the output of the printcp() function to a dataframe and then use some logic to extract the CP value for the lowest CV error. Is there anyway I can do this, WITHOUT printing the output of printcp to the console?

```
  df_tree_1 <- rpart(formula(df_lm_2), cp = 0.0001, data = train)
  cp_df <- data.frame(printcp(df_tree_1))
  df_tree_1 <- prune.rpart(tree = df_tree_1, cp = cp_df$CP[which(cp_df$xerror == min(cp_df$xerror))])
```

Comment: The `printcp` function doesn't seem to be in base. If you are using non-standard packages you should include the necessary `library()` calls in the code. Additionally, you should provide sample data to make the problem [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can copy and paste the code into R to re-create the same error you get. That makes it much easier to help you and test any possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rpart()`-fitted tree object contains the "`cptable`" table containing the value you're looking for. The `printcp()` function just displays this table, so what you really seem to want to do is just return the value dynamically when running `prune()`. Here's how you could do that:

```
library(rpart)  # for the rpart function
library(rattle) # for "weather" dataset and for "fancy" tree plotter

# fit model using rpart
fit <- rpart(RainTomorrow ~ Rainfall + Evaporation + Sunshine + WindGustDir, 
             data = weather,
             method = "class")

# visualize with rattle
fancyRpartPlot(fit)

# prune by returning the value in the column of fit$cptable (a table)
# corresponding to the row that has the minimum "xerror" value
fit_autoprune <- prune(tree = fit,
                       cp = fit$cptable[which.min(fit$cptable[, "xerror"]),
                                        "CP"])

# visualize again to see difference
fancyRpartPlot(fit_autoprune)
```